# Why can't I run my node packages from the terminal?

Tags: npm, node-modules

Good evening,

I tried installing `sails`, `yo`, `gulp` & `bower` via the usual methods of `npm i -g yo gulp bower` etc but each time I open the terminal to run the command I always get the `-bash: sails: command not found` error.

I listed all my folders at the root of my folder and found the following:
[image]

The contents of the `.npm-global/bin/` is actually all the packages I'm trying to use at the command line.

I decided to manual add the `bin` folder to the `.bash_profile` so it's contents was the following:

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.7
# The original version is saved in su

export PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH="/.npm-global/bin:${PATH}"
```

but that didn't work either.

Here's where I think the problem first arose - I think that the `python` install overrode all the previous paths in the file (or moved them somewhere perhaps?) so that all previous terminal commands now don't work.

The usual global install for node packages (`/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin`) contains the following:

[image]

What am I misunderstanding here & how can I fix this?

Comment: How did you install node? Homebrew?

Comment: It was a while ago but I believe so - brew is recognized as a command so I'm assuming so.

Comment: That's weird, usually global executables go in `/usr/local/bin`

Comment: I think they did but when i installed/updated python to 3.7 it moved the references to them. Any suggestions?

Comment: Symlink them back over? IDK I purged all non-brew python installs because of problems like this.

Comment: @JaredSmith I'll give that a shot tonight Jared. If that doesn't work I may need to wipe out node completely and reinstall

Comment: I tried the symlink and it didn't work - I had to completely uninstall node & npm and then reinstall them via nvm. After that Sails installed easily.

Comment: Glad you got it solved